# How to integrate icici Payment Gateway in Mobile?

Tags: android, ios, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I'm searching for the integration guide on ICICI payseal payment gateway for mobile platforms but I'm not finding any resource for that. Have anyone integrated before and please share your inputs on integrating it on iOS and Android?

Also, from the information I searched it should be the payseal URL that we should load it on a `UIWebView`. If so, how could we handle the success or failure responses?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate citrus payment that allows icici payment mode 
[citrus](https://developers.citruspay.com)

Comment: Yeah, If I have the option to go I would happily do. But, our client has existing merchant account for ICICI Merchant services in web application. I have to stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

ICIC do not provide any Android supportive platform or code, you will have to get it done using web, Send Request to web page from app and capture request from webpage and process based on gateway response. Please let us know

Answer (score 0):

you can try their web integration kit and do a integration in web view , that will solve your issue, as ICICI do not provide kit for android.